# Using jinja to return a list of values from complex dict structure

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

What I would like to do is to get a list of urls i.e. `[url1, url2, url3, url4, url5, url6, url7]` from the following dict, so that I can assign this to a variable in my Ansible playbook:

```
dict:
  site1:
    domains:
      - canonical: url1
        redirects:
          - url2
          - url3
  site2:
    domains:
      - canonical: url4
        redirects:
          - url5
          - url6
          - url7
```

I've been playing around with all kinds of filters and not managed to get anything that works so far. Hopefully someone who's better than me at jinja can help out. Thanks.

Comment: How does jinja work into this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_query` may help:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    dict:
      site1:
        domains:
          - canonical: url1
            redirects:
              - url2
              - url3
      site2:
        domains:
          - canonical: url4
            redirects:
              - url5
              - url6
              - url7
  tasks:
    # get redirects
    - debug: msg="{{ dict | json_query('*.domains[].redirects[]') }}"
    # get all urls
    - debug: msg="{{ dict | json_query('*.domains[].{c:to_array(canonical),r:redirects} | [].*[][]') }}"
```

Comment: Looks like [json_query](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) is new in Ansible 2.2. Thanks for this. I had no idea this filter was introduced.